# Javascript/ Underscore JS Data transformation based from two arrays for display in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, transformation

I have two arrays, one a 'groups' array, and the other, an object 'items' array. I want to transform the data with these conditions:

1. If the group doesn't exist in the 'groups' array it will be marked as 'false', else 'true'.
2. The 'group' array attribute in the 'result' array correspond with the 'groups' array's position that if I change the position of 'group1' with 'group2', the corresponding 'groups' array attribute in the 'result' array should also change the position.
3. 'Group' attribute array size in the 'result' array should be the same as the size of the 'groups' array.

You may only use underscore.js if it may help. Thanks!

```
var groups = ["group1", "group2"]       // Can increase dynamically, e.g. ["group1", "group2", "group3"],
var items =                             // Given that the 'group' attribute of each item should correspond dynamically too with groups array increase/ decrease
[                                       // It can become ["group1", "group2", "group3"] as values in an item when the 'groups' array is ["group1", "group2", "group3"]
    {
        name: "object 1",
        group: ["group1"]
    },
    {
        name: "object 2",
        group: ["group1", "group2"]
    },
    {
        name: "object 3",
        group: ["group2"]
    }
]
```

It should transform to this:

```
var result =
[
    {
        name: "object 1",
        group: ["true", "false"]        // group attribute order should base on the groups array and increase in size as groups increase
    },                                  // true in the first value since it has "group1" in the 'group' array attribute in the 'items' array and false as the second value because it doesn't have "group2"
    {
        name: "object 2",
        group: ["true", "true"]
    },
    {
        name: "object 3",
        group: ["false", "true"]
    }
]
```

And BTW, this will be used for displaying data in a table in an angular JS app. Where the column headers are the 'groups' array and the rows are the 'result' array.

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: question was already answered below, but as of that moment, I've wrote and tried different logic many times to achieve my desired result but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var groups = ["group1", "group2"]       // Can increase dynamically, e.g. ["group1", "group2", "group3"],
var items =                             // Given that the 'group' attribute of each item should correspond dynamically too with groups array increase/ decrease
[                                       // It can become ["group1", "group2", "group3"] as values in an item when the 'groups' array is ["group1", "group2", "group3"]
    {
        name: "object 1",
        group: ["group1"]
    },
    {
        name: "object 2",
        group: ["group1", "group2"]
    },
    {
        name: "object 3",
        group: ["group2"]
    }
];

function transform(items, groups) {
 return _.map(items, function(item) {
   var groupsTransformed = _.map(groups, function(group) {
    return (item.group.indexOf(group) >= 0);
   });
   item.group = groupsTransformed;
   return item;
 });
}

var transformedData = transform(items, groups);
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(transformedData);
console.log(transformedData);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9ftob9k/)